# Blazor fail when attempting to "getItem()" from browser sessionStorage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to retrieve a value from window.sessionStorage in my BLazor application. I have been able to successfully SET the value. It's when I go to retreive it that it simply stops ... no error or anything ... it just hits the function and stops.

I have my code set up in a "Code-Behind" structure so my .razor page is inheriting from a BASE class. In that base class is where I am storing all the logic.

This is the RAZOR page ...

```
@page "/PhotoViewer"
@inherits PhotoViewerBase

<h3>Photo Viewer</h3>

<p>ActiveMediaCode: @ActiveMediaCode</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@btn_OnClick">Push it</button>
```

And this is PhotoViewerBase that it inherits from ...

```
namespace IF.APP.BlabaBoothBlazor.Pages
{
    public class PhotoViewerBase : Models.PageBase
    {

        protected String ActiveMediaCode { get; set; }

        protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {

            }

            return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
        }

        protected void btn_OnClick()
        {
            ActiveMediaCode = GetMediaCodeAsync().Result;
        }

    }
}

namespace IF.APP.BlabaBoothBlazor.Models
{
    public class PageBase : ComponentBase
    {

        [Inject]
        protected IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }

        [Inject]
        protected NavigationManager Navigator { get; set; }

        public async Task<String> GetMediaCodeAsync()
        {
            // STOPS PROCESSING HERE
            return await JS.InvokeAsync<String>("sessionStorage.getItem", "ActiveMediaCode"); 
        }

        public async Task SetMediaCodeAsync(String mediaCode)
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("sessionStorage.setItem", "ActiveMediaCode", mediaCode);
        }

    }
}
```

The **SetMediaCodeAsync()** method works with no problem. But when I click on the Button on the razor page I step through to  the **GetMediaCodeAsync()** method and, where commented above, the debugger just stops. It doesn't drop out of debug mode ... just nothing. My output window begins to report that threads are gracefully shutting down but not errors or exceptions.

I am making the call AFTER the page has loaded in the browser, ensuring that the sessionStorage is available.

Just looking for a fresh perspective and maybe some ideas ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 ActiveMediaCode = GetMediaCodeAsync().Result;
```

is a very wrong way to do async. It probably deadlocks.

Replace

```
protected void btn_OnClick()
{
    ActiveMediaCode = GetMediaCodeAsync().Result;
}
```

with

```
protected async Task btn_OnClick()
{
    ActiveMediaCode = await GetMediaCodeAsync();
}
```

don't change the razor markup, that is fine.

Comment: For context: https://montemagno.com/c-sharp-developers-stop-calling-dot-result/

Comment: Holy cow ... I would have bet $$$ I had already tried this ... but upon trying again ... it worked!! Thanks a ton!